# Scroll left and right between images in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

http://imgur.com/CxlW4Pj

What is this animation call? How can I do animation like this in iOS?

Where the user can scroll between images and display relevant details about the image that is currently being selected. 
And also, the images on the left and right are not being selected therefore it is a bit blurry.

Are there any functions or libraries that could do that?

Comment: please check: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a carousel. Or Cover flow...

**[iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)** is one amazing open source library for this.

Try out these display types from iCarousel:

- iCarouselTypeCoverFlow
- iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2

Images will be shown like this :

[image]

There are a lot of different settings which you can tweak in this library, however for the blur, you might need to add two overlay views which blur the images on the side or something like that. This library provides **reflection** and **shadow** effects by default, but does not have a blur effect as far as I know.